# check if formgroup is visible

Tags: actionscript, coldfusion, visible

I have a coldfusion flash form.  (Unfortunately don't have time to change to html/javascript)  In the form I have a formgroup.

I would like to be able to use actionscript to detect if the formgroup is visible.

I've used the code:

if(formgroupid.visible == "true"){
   do this
}

However, this does not work.  Any ideas to alter the if statement to get the code to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is `visible` a string or a boolean?

Try:

```
if (formgroupid.visible) {do this}
```